# MUnit error : A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Tags: installation, mule, anypoint-studio, munit

I follow tutorial to install MUnit plugin as this page: https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.1.1/using-munit-in-anypoint-studio

But, when I run an empty test case, AnyPoint return me an error as: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.

In console, I saw the exception as:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mule/munit/runner/mule/result/notification/NotificationListener at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source) at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source) at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.munit.runner.mule.result.notification.NotificationListener at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ... 7 more

Please help to check whats the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there, 
MUnit empty tests are not a valid construct, same as an empty flow  is not valid. 
That said, an empty MUnit tests should not throw such an error and I wasn't able to reproduce it. 
Could you pelase share an example to reproduce?
Also it'll be of grate help to know: Mule version, MUnit version, if you got this error when running from Anypoint Studio or from the maven command line and finally which operating system you're on. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming a few things here: 1) You are using Anypoint Studio and 2) Your project is Mavenized

1) Install MUnit:
Go to Help menu in the Anypoint Studio and Click on *Install New Software* . In the *Work With* column enter http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/munit and add.

Once it is done, we need to add this MUnit to the Maven Path.

2) Adding to Path:
In your project explorer go to *src/test/munit* and right click on it. From the DropDown select *Munit* and select *Configure MUnit Maven Support*.

After this Maven will automatically trigger a build and all the necessary files including the one you have mentioned in the question will be downloaded.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the MUnit runner at runtime.  You can resolve the issue by adding munit runner to my pom.

**Dependency**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
<artifactId>mule-munit-support</artifactId>
<version>${mule.munit.support.version}</version>
<scope>test</scope>
```

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
<artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
<version>${munit.version}</version>
<scope>test</scope>
```

**plugin**

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <coverage>
                    <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                    </formats>
                </coverage>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Also remember to add you munit source as maven test resource like,

```
<testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/munit</directory>
        </testResource>
    <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources
```